# Ruby Mongo Driver - Find_by_Id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

What am I doing wrong here? I know the _id is in the database but I get empty result.

```
@b = coll.find("_id" => "4db2ebee90036f010b000001")
```

Thanks

Comment: does it return anything if you execute the same by hand in db?

Comment: @Vlad, I'm using MongoHQ and in fact when I search for {_id: "4db2ebee90036f010b000001" } I get no results. However, I don't understand why. The row is there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this:

```
coll.find(:_id => BSON::ObjectId('4db2ebee90036f010b000001')).each do |data| 
   puts data.inspect 
end
```

Answer (score 9):

@b will contain a cursor, not the result. You also need to use an object id proper.

You probably want this:

```
@b = coll.find_one(:_id => BSON::ObjectId('4db2ebee90036f010b000001'))
```

Answer (score 2):

With Ruby 1.9.3 and mongoid 3.0.19

```
@coll = Coll.find( hash["_id"] )
```

or

```
@coll = Coll.find( "511296d2dfa18f07fa000009" )
```

find the record. Will only ever be one, _id is the primary key, it can never be double.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like `first` which returns a object since you have bigger problems if your primary id is duplicated in your database. The syntax is depending on your mongo gem version this one is for 2.1.0.

```
your_id = '4db2ebee90036f010b000001'
db = Client.new([ "localhost:27017" ], :database => "db")
coll = db[:testCollection]
res = coll.find(:_id => BSON::ObjectId(your_id)).first
```

Answer (score 1):

Using, Ruby version 2.3.1p112, mongo (gem) 2.4.2 and BSON (gem) 4.2.2

The following worked for me

```
client = Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:3001'], :database=>'dbname')
collection = client[:users]
user = collection.find({_id:'XY3h5R7aJkh5FxFhJ'}).first
```